# Using echo command with -n option doesn't print the variable

Tags: bash, echo

I am extracting a string variable from a file and then print it to the screen. The problem is that using just `echo` works, but if I used `echo -n`, then nothing is printed. Here is an example:

```
$ Var=$(grep -a MrEdbType FileName)
$ echo $Var
Prot
$ echo -n $Var
$
```

Similarly, if I use `printf`, it works only if I add `\n`:

```
$ Var=$(grep -a MrEdbType FileName)
$ printf "%s" $Var
$
$ printf "%s\n" $Var
Prot
```

What is wrong with the string I am extracting? The file is a DICOM file containing a mixture of text and binary data, hence the use of `-a` option.

As suggested in the comments, using `hexdump -C` option generated this result:

```
$ Var=$(grep -a MrEdbType FileName | hexdump -C)
$ echo $Var
00000000 50 72 6f 74 0d 0a |Prot..| 00000006
```

Comment: Add output of `grep -a MrEdbType FileName | hexdump -C` to your question.

Comment: try `dos2unix FileName` before grepping

Comment: You are suffering from CRLF endings. To demonstrate try `$ echo "foo\r"` and `$ echo -n "foo\r"`

Comment: Also related: [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525)

Comment: If you look at http://www.asciitable.com/, then you notice that `0D` is the hexadecimal value for CR (`\r`)

Answer (score 0):

A suggested link led to an answer - using `sed 's/\r$//'` at the end of the `grep` search fixed the problem!